# Oracle query by date and number for bar chart

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have this table which I use to store 4 types of messages: info, warn, alarm and error.

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

I need to display the events by type and day in a bar chart 15 days into the past for example:[image]

Can you help me for this Oracle query?

Example output from query:

```
|11-12-2015 | 12 | 22 | 11 |
|12-12-2015 | 32 | 12 | 14 |
|13-12-2015 | 12 | 22 | 11 |
|14-12-2015 | 12 | 22 | 11 |
```

Comment: Oracle queries return result sets, not bar charts.  Please show the results that you want in a tabular format.

Comment: And what are the values for (12 | 22 | 11)? What is Source, what Type? Type values = info, error, warn?

Comment: Well for example these are the values for the `TYPE VARCHAR2(50 )` - info, warn, alarm and error.

Comment: Ok, that's the count? I understand, okay maybe you want this...

Comment: Yes, the count of the events by type 15 days into the past.

Comment: If there are four `type` values, wouldn't you want 5 columns of output (the day and then the count of info, the count of warn, the count of alarm, and the count of error)?

Comment: Yes Justin - this is just a basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select event_date,
       sum(case when type = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) as Error,
       sum(case when type = 'Warn' then 1 else 0 end) as Warn,
       sum(case when type = 'Info' then 1 else 0 end) as Info
from events e
where event_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 15
group by event_date
order by event_date;
```

Caveat:  if the field called `event_date` actually has a time component, then you should use `trunc(event_date)` in the `select` and `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

**Variant A: line by line**
You want the number (=COUNT(*)) of e.g. error (=TYPE) events of a specific source at a specific event_date. So the triple ( source, type, event_date) build a group and you want to know, how many events are in this group.

```
Select source, type, event_date, count(*) 
from events 
group by source, type, event_date;
```

With this the results would be

```
event_date  source  type   count
11-12-2015  server  error  12
11-12-2015  server  info   22
11-12-2015  server  warn   11
12-12-2015  server  error  32
12-12-2015  server  info   12
12-12-2015  server  warn   14
```

**Variant B: side by side**

```
Select event_date, source, sum(error), sum(info), sum(warn)
From (select event_date, source, 
decode(Type, 'error', 1, 0) as error,
decode(Type, 'info', 1, 0) as info,
decode(Type, 'warn', 1, 0) as warn
From events)
Group by event_date, source;
```

You should get:

```
event_date  source  error  warn  info
11-12-2015  server   12    22    11
12-12-2015  server   32    12    14
```

`decode` is some kind of if-then-else.

**Optional: only 15 days back**
As you asked.

Simple add where clause to the (inner) select, like `where event_date >= sysdate - 15`

```
Select source, type, event_date, count(*) 
from events 
where event_date >= sysdate - 15
group by source, type, event_date;
```

or for b)

```
Select event_date, source, sum(error), sum(info), sum(warn)
From (select event_date, source, 
decode(Type, 'error', 1, 0) as error,
decode(Type, 'info', 1, 0) as info,
decode(Type, 'warn', 1, 0) as warn
From events
where event_date >= sysdate - 15)
Group by event_date, source;
```

Comment: Oh, I just recognize, that there are a fourth value for type: alarm. But I think you can see the idea. To expand the second variant you have only to add another column. The first variant is more flexible and works always, with one or with hundred values for type.